# Establish a secure connection with HTTP proxy

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, http-proxy

I am trying to create a HTTP client which has to reach out to a origin server in public network via a forward proxy. The communication with the proxy as well as the origin server has to be mutual TLS.

I tried using python's requests library for doing this -

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import Timeout, ConnectionError

origin_url="https://origin_server.com/"
CA_CHAIN_FILE = 'ca.pem'
SERVER_KEY = 'server.cer'
PRIV_KEY = 'private.key'

auth_tuple = None
timeout_sec = 5
proxies = {
    'https': 'https://fwd_proxy.cust1.com:8445'
}
headers = { 'User-Agent': 'My User Agent' }
payload = {}

resp = requests.get(origin_url, data=payload, verify=CA_CHAIN_FILE, auth=auth_tuple, headers=headers, cert=(SERVER_KEY, PRIV_KEY),  timeout=timeout_sec, proxies=proxies)
```

But the above code sends an HTTP CONNECT in plain text and does not establish an ssl connection with the proxy first. Is there a way to achieve this using requests library or any other python module?